# Create a grid and assign values

Tags: c++

I would like to create a 2D squared grid of the world with a definite spacing (say d)

```
-180 =< j =< 180
-90 =< k =< 90

Grid[j][k]
```

and then assign to each cell the lon lat points that I have stored in two arrays

```
0 =< i < N

Lon[i]
Lat[i]
```

to group the observations by cells.

I was thinking of using nested loops to create the grid but I am not really sure how to to that.

Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
struct Position {
  double Lon, Lat;
    int index;
};

int main(){
printf ("\n");


    static const double arrlon[] = {100,180,180};   
    static const double arrlat[] = {0,2,3};
    static const int arrind[] = {0,0,0};
    vector<double> londat (arrlon, arrlon + sizeof(arrlon) / sizeof(arrlon[0]));
    vector<double> latdat (arrlat, arrlat + sizeof(arrlat) / sizeof(arrlat[0]));
    vector<int> index (arrind, arrind + sizeof(arrind) / sizeof(arrind[0]));
    int N = sizeof(arrlat)/ sizeof(arrlat[0]) ;

    const int lonCount = 360;
    const int latCount = 180;
    const int step = 5;

    Position positions[lonCount+1][latCount+1];
    Position* p;

    int count = 0;
    for(int lon = 0; lon <= 360; lon=lon+step){
    for(int lat = 0; lat <= 180; lat=lat+step){
      p = &positions[lon][lat];
      p->Lon = lon;
      p->Lat = lat;
            p->index = count;
            count++;
            for (int i = 0; i<N ; i++){
                if(londat[i] >= p->Lon && londat[i] < p->Lon+step && latdat[i] >= p->Lat && latdat[i] < p->Lat+step) index[i] = p->index;
            }
       }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<N ; i++) cerr << i << "   " << index[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should note that it's a little weird to ask a question, accept an answer, post your own answer, unaccept the previous answer and accept your own.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to be yelled at by the SO community for a novice question without a lot of signs of research. But here's my obligatory answer.

```
struct Position
{
    double Lon, Lat;
}

const unsigned short lonCount = 180;
const unsigned short latCount = 360;

Position positions[lonCount][latCount];

for( unsigned short lon = -90; lon <= 90; lon++ )
{
    for( unsigned short lat = -180; lat <= 180; lat++ )
    {
        Position* p = &positions[lon + lonCount / 2][lat + latCount / 2];
        p->Lon = lon;
        p->Lat = lat;
    }
}
```

This should get you started.